# Many to many relationship through association

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following models:

Group:

```py
class Group(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Groups'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)
    users = db.relationship(
        "User",
        secondary=users_groups_assocation_table,
        back_populates="groups")
    analysis = db.relationship(
        "Analysis",
        secondary=analysis_groups_assocation_table,
        back_populates="groups"
```

User:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Users'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    alias = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), index=False, nullable=True)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    local_auth = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    override_tableau = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    groups = db.relationship(
        "Group",
        secondary=users_groups_assocation_table,
        back_populates="users")
```

Analysis:

```py
class Analysis(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'Analysis'
  __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
  description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
  embed_analysis = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
  service_account = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
  img = db.Column(db.LargeBinary(length=(2**32)-1), nullable=True)
  img_mimetype = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
  img_name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
  category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Categories.id'), nullable=True)
  created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
  updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)
  category = db.relationship("Category", back_populates="analysis")
  draft = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
  groups = db.relationship(
        "Group",
        secondary=analysis_groups_assocation_table,
        back_populates="analysis")
```

Association tables:

```py
users_groups_assocation_table = db.Table('users_groups',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id')),
    db.Column('group_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Groups.id'))
)

analysis_groups_assocation_table = db.Table('analysis_groups',
    db.Column('analysis_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Analysis.id')),
    db.Column('group_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Groups.id'))
)
```

So there is an implicimit many to many relationship between Users <-> Analysis. How do I create such an association through `groups`? Coming from ruby on rails there is a :through keyword in this case, is there anything similar for flask sqlalchemy?

I want to have something like `User.query.first().analysis`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many things are possible with sqlalchemy's relationships but I find that complex ones can be hard to get right/predictable and that one-off queries are easier to maintain (at least for complex relationships).

I attempted to solve the relationship you asked about, as `User.analyses` but included a one off query at the end.

I used a simplified version of joining across multiple tables in the docs here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#composite-secondary-join

Note that the join uses a mix of `Table` objects that require columns referenced of `.c.` and mapped classes like `Analysis` that have columns directly referenced.

You also probably would want an `order_by` argument to `relationship` otherwise this relation would probably be meaningless.

```py
from datetime import datetime, date
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Text,
    Integer,
    String,
    ForeignKey,
    UniqueConstraint,
    update,
    DateTime,
   Date,
    Boolean,
    LargeBinary,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Table,
    Column,
    MetaData,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError


Base = declarative_base()


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=False)

users_groups_table = Table('users_groups', Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('Users.id')),
    Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('Groups.id'))
)

analysis_groups_table = Table('analysis_groups', Base.metadata,
    Column('analysis_id', Integer, ForeignKey('Analysis.id')),
    Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('Groups.id'))
)

class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Groups'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    users = relationship(
        "User",
        secondary=users_groups_table,
        back_populates="groups")
    analysis = relationship(
        "Analysis",
        secondary=analysis_groups_table,
        back_populates="groups")

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Users'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(120), index=True, unique=False)
    groups = relationship(
        "Group",
        secondary=users_groups_table,
        back_populates="users")
    analyses = relationship("Analysis",
                            # The middle
                            secondary="join(users_groups, analysis_groups, users_groups.c.group_id == analysis_groups.c.group_id)",
                            # Join from left to the middle
                            primaryjoin="User.id == users_groups.c.user_id",
                            # Join from right to the middle
                            secondaryjoin="Analysis.id == analysis_groups.c.analysis_id",
                uselist=True,
                viewonly=True
                )

class Analysis(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'Analysis'
  __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String(120), index=True, unique=True)
  groups = relationship(
        "Group",
        secondary=analysis_groups_table,
        back_populates="analysis")



Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    users = {}
    for name in ('a', 'b'):
        users[name] = User(name=name)
        session.add(users[name])
    groups = {}
    for name in ('a', 'b'):
        groups[name] = Group(name=name)
        session.add(groups[name])
    analyses = {}
    for name in ('x', 'y', 'z'):
        analyses[name] = Analysis(name=name)
        session.add(analyses[name])

    groups['a'].users.append(users['a'])
    groups['b'].users.append(users['b'])
    analyses['x'].groups.append(groups['a'])
    analyses['y'].groups.append(groups['b'])
    analyses['z'].groups.append(groups['b'])

    session.commit()

    print (users['a'].analyses[0].name)

    # One-off ad-hoc query.
    q = session.query(Analysis).join(Analysis.groups).join(Group.users).filter(User.id == users['a'].id)
    print (q)
    res = q.first()
    print (res.name)
```